# Laravel doesn't display php properly

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new with laravel and I'm not really sure if I explained the problem properly. The things is, it was given to me the code from an already existing website to upgrade it visually. But i can't make the visual part of the website work.
I started by checking if it was because i was opening the file instead of using localhost, because its a common mistake, but I was doing it right.
So I'll add an image to show what's my problem

[image]

Hope someone can help me,
Thanks in advance

Comment: did you install laravel? which means, did you do composer install, npm install , changed your .env file

Comment: i did install the laravel, i didn't changed the .env file because it isn't there. The project wasn't created by me, they just passed me their code, so this is quite messy for me

Comment: if your .env file isn't there, create it . generate a key with : php artisan key:generate  and change the values in your .env file to match your database

Comment: That's the problem, i don't know anything about the database. I'm an intern right now and they asked me to make the content of this section of their website acording to the their norms ( Visual upgrade it basically), I expected to only work with their css, but considering your answer, i tried ot generate a key through cmd and doesn't work, should i use the composer?

Comment: I provided an answer with the basic contents of the .env file. And since you are an intern just ask your boss for the database settings.

Comment: are you sure you have php installed on your system ? can you create a new file named info.php inside public folder and save it with the following contents <?php phpinfo();?> and then try opening it if it shows an informative page that means yes else you need to setup your php first

Comment: I did what you asked, and it showed the informative page of php, when I installed composer it showed that I had the v5.6.25 so I was pretty confident that wasn't the problem

Answer (score 2):

You need to save the php file as NAMEHERE.blade.php 
Read more here https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade

Comment: I did read the documentation but didn't understand completely, if you are saying that the Views need to be saved as FILENAME.blade.php I already did that, I remember that I need to change the name of the php.ini-production/documentation to only php.ini, not sure if that's very important though

Comment: You need to be running the laravel project either with php artisan:serve or xampp or something.If you're using xampp,or some sort you need to access it like this : localhost/projectname/public , if you're using php artisan serve localhost:8000

Comment: Im using wamp to run the project, the url Im using to open it is localhost/projectname/resources/views/layouts/master.blade.php, which as the code for the general layout of the website

Comment: Laravel uses routing do know what action to do and what to return to you. Also you have blade that does an template engine to that. That seems to be a template layout, so you should go to : localhost/projectname/public and from there on you're actually loading the php

Comment: It seems that there isn't a public folder inside the project, is it a possible reason to make it not work?

Comment: Can you send a screenshot of what the project folder looks like?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ecd1hf here is all i have in the project folder, can send from the others folders if necessary

Comment: Do you know what version you're running of laravel? i'm not sure if its an older version that i don't know the directory structure or if you're missing a folder

Comment: I seached and couldn't find out, 
vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php it was said that this was a path to a file with the version, but i don't find it anywhere

Comment: open a command line inside the project folder and run composer update

Comment: I did that on the original project and it showed up a fatal error, I created a new project and placed the routes, views, controllers and models in it, and it allowed me to start the update but ended showing the same error as the previous
"Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:/wamp64/www/project/../vendor/autoload.php'"

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you missed extension of view file.

It should be `filename.blade.php`

Comment: This is the page with the code to the general website layout, do i still need to extend it?
For example, the page for new orders has the 
@extends('layouts.master') line to extend the layout of the homepage to it

Answer (score 0):

Based on the screenshot of your folder structure provided in the comments: http://prnt.sc/ecd1hf .

You are missing an .env file

So create the .env file in the root of your project. [The contents of a basic .env file for laravel 5.4](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/.env.example) and run the following command to generate a key:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

you will also need to add your database info and any other important info in this file.

Also make sure Composer/npm/... is installed correctly

1. First run: Composer install
2. After that: npm install (since i did not see a yarn.lock file)
3. i noticed a gulpfile.js so make sure to run gulp after you installed npm, the command for this is: gulp

Comment: Based on your first answer, I checked the folder and all the visual content is placed in a img folder on project/resources/assets, maybe that's suposed to be the database

Comment: no no, thats all correct. assets contains your css/js/images etc . Your database will be seperate from your project . you have to have credentials to log into it. those credentials need to be placed inside your .env file. You will need to ask for those credentials to your boss or co-worker

Comment: Ok, I'll do that. Hopefully when I connect the database to the project It finally shows the visual part of the website. Thank you!

Comment: the database is not responsible for that, but the .env is necessarry . i'll add the steps after that too. I noticed you have gulpfile.js in your project which means you need to also run gulp for the assets to compile correctly. i'll edit my answer